# Set of four vectors in R4 - Matrices and coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems

Just started with linear algebra. Going through some practice problems, and this one I'm having difficulty with. Don't know where to begin.

[heres the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tzAc.png)

Thanks!

Comment: **Hint**: You can try to put those vectors in a matrix and do the determinant. If the determinant is zero, or it isn't, what can you say?

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci That part I could do. Just check if the determinant is zero it doesn't span R4. But, I'm more stuck on finding the coordinate.